# Using npm to get JavaScript to add to a web page

Tags: node.js

I'm making a web page `index.html` say.

I used to download jQuery.min.js and put it in the same folder and add to `index.html` the tag `".

Then I got a bit more sophisticated and replaced the `src` with the URL of a CDN.

Now I've been told that I have to use `npm` and `webpack`. I see that `npm` creates a folder `node_modules`. So do I just `src="node_modules/jquery/jquery.min.js"`?

Comment: you're trying to add `jQuery`, not `JavaScript`. And, yeah, add the path of the `jquery.min.js` should work.

Comment: I'm trying to get some JavaScript, jQuery is an example of some JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

Refer [here](https://www.valentinog.com/blog/webpack-4-tutorial/#webpack_4_transpiling_Javascript_ES6_with_Babel)

You simply place it under `scripts:` array in your webpack configuration file.